# C# program to count how many strings have the same first and last chars as these in a list

Tags: c#, string, list

I need to write a program to count the number of strings where the string length is 2 or more and the first and last character are same as these in certain list with strings 
["people", "desk", "orange", "yellow", "carrot", "pineapple"]

example:
Input: "pe" , result- 2 
-same as  “people” и “pineapple ”

For now I did this, it search if the first and last chars are the same:

```
        List<string> stringsList = new List<string> { "people", "desk", "orange", "yellow", "carrot", "pineapple"};

        int count = 0;

        foreach (var c in stringsList)
        {
            if (c.Length > 1 && c[0] == c[-1])
            {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Comment: C# arrays do not support negative indexes.  If you want the last character, use the length of the string minus one.  But this code isn't doing what the question describes.  You are comparing the first character of the word to the last character of the word, not the two characters "pe".

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for this purpose. So you need to

- filter by length
- compare the first letter with input
- compare the final letter with input

So code looks like this:

```
List<string> stringsList = new List<string> { "people", "desk", "orange", 
    "yellow", "carrot", "pineapple" };

int count = 0;
var input = "pe";
count = stringsList.Where(s => s.Length > 2 
            &&  s[0] == input[0] 
            && s[s.Length - 1] == input[1])
            .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer below:

```
   //I'll let you input however you want to. Probably use console.ReadLine();
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int count;
    List<string> stringsList = new List<string> { "people", "desk", "orange", "yellow", "carrot", "pineapple"};

            foreach (string item in stringsList)
            {
                if (input.Length > 1 && item.Length > 1)
                {
                    if(input[input.Length - 1] == item[item.Length - 1])
                    {
                        //Same Last character
                        if(input[0] == item[0])
                        {
                            //Same first character
                            count += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

List<string> stringsList = new List<string> { 
  "people", "desk", "orange", "yellow", "carrot", "pineapple"
};

string input = "pe";

int count = stringsList
  .Count(word => word.Length >= 2 && 
                 word[0] == input[0] && 
                 word[word.Length - 1] == input[input.Length - 1]);
```

Or even

```
int count = stringsList
  .Count(word => word.Length >= 2 && 
                 word.First() == input.First() && 
                 word.Last() == input.Last());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#8 and .Net Core 3, you can use the new "index from end" operator to get at the last character of a string, to simplify the code somewhat.

For example, the last character of a string `str` is given by `str[^1]`.

So you could use the Linq `Count()` operator to count all the strings of length >=2 where the first and last characters match the target; for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CoreConsole
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<string> stringsList = new List<string> { "people", "desk", "orange", "yellow", "carrot", "pineapple" };

            string search = "pe";

            int n = stringsList.Count(str => 
                str.Length >= 2
                && str[ 0] == search[0] 
                && str[^1] == search[1]);

            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this is what I did:

```
        foreach (var c in stringsList)
        {
            if (c.Length > 1 && c[0] == input[0] && c[c.Length-1] == input[1])
            {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
```